# dialogflow support for Finnish

Tags: dialogflow-es

Has anyone implemented a chatbot using Dialogflow for Finnish.
I know it is not supported natively yet. But i havent seen any clear roadmap for the supported languages in the coming months. Any feedback or information on this.

If not dialogflow, what other NLP would you recommend to implement a Finnish chatbot.

Also would it be a good idea to try to administer the intents in English and use Translator APIs to translate user text from Finnish to English and do the intent matching on Dialogflow. Obviously the matched intent response has to be translated back to Finnish when delivered to the customer.

Regards,

Ujjwal

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Support for **Finnish** is added now.

Dialog-flow currently doesn't list **Finnish** in their
[language list](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/language). *(If your use-case is urgent, you shouldn't wait for its additive support in near future)*

> Necessity is the mother of invention

Before Proceeding, I wouldn't recommend you to use Translator API's to convert English and Finnish, vice versa. It will not train the model exactly you want to because relationship between words, across languages are very different.

**NLTK** is a great NLP library with all the features which you can use to develop the chatbot in Finnish. [Stemming with Finnish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voOfX.png)

**Note**: Apart from NLTK, SpaCy and TextBlob are also great NLP libraries you can use. **If a library doesn't support a particular language, you can use UNI-Code to train.**

**ALSO** You could use various openly available modules to develop your bot.
Like this one, https://github.com/TurkuNLP/Finnish-dep-parser

*With this in mind, NLP applied with basic Word2Vec and Markov Models (Many options you can find over the internet) will help you to build the chatbot you want.*

*Cheers to building your chatbot*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response !. I will try out the suggested options.

Answer (score 1):

[Dialogflow ES](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/language) and [Dialogflow CX](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/language) now support Finnish.